# From Host, Can't Connect to OpenLDAP server installed on VM

Tags: linux, centos, ldap, openldap

I have created an OpenLDAP install on a CentOS Hyper-V VM hosted on my Windows 10 laptop. Using Apache Directory Studio (on the VM), I have created a connection, setup up the domain, and added Groups and People.

The IP address of the VM is `172.16.22.150`. On my host machine, if I ping that IP, I get back a response. If I then shut down the VM and ping the IP again, this time I get no response. Power the VM back up, ping, get a response.  So it looks like the IP is good.

So far, all is well. However...

First, I've installed Apache Directory Studio on my host machine as well. But when I try to create the same connection, I get

> The connection failed -unable to connect.

Details:

```
The connection failed
 - Unable to connect
  java.lang.Exception: Unable to connect
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper$1.run(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:251)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1312)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.doConnect(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:281)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.connect(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:172)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.jobs.CheckNetworkParameterRunnable.run(CheckNetworkParameterRunnable.java:80)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.ui.RunnableContextRunner$1.run(RunnableContextRunner.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)

  Unable to connect
```

Second, I need to create a small little c# console app as a PoC to connect to the server and authenticate a user. Oddly, I can connect to the server just fine using:

```
LdapDirectoryIdentifier ldi = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("172.16.22.150");
LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(ldi);
```

But when I try to authenticate a user:

```
ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("ccrookston", "password", "mydomain.com");
ldapConnection.Bind(nc);
```

I get:

> The LDAP server is unavailable.

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.Connect()
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.BindHelper(NetworkCredential newCredential, Boolean needSetCredential)
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.Bind(NetworkCredential newCredential)
   at OpenLDAP.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\caseyc\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\OpenLDAP\Program.cs:line 33
```

I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting this. Is it a configuration within CentOS on the VM? Is it a Hyper-V configuration? Or something on my Windows Host machine, like a firewall setting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
In the firewall (using the GUI) I added ports:

389 - tcp
389 - udp

It seems to need both.